# How to select the latest record based on version number?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Hi i have a table called `T1(id,number,version)`

and contains data like

```
1,123,1
2,123,2
3,345,1
5,123,3
```

now i need to retrieve the latest record based on the version i.e. the output should be like this

```
3,345,1
5,123,3
```

for this i have writen the following query but it is not working

```
select bd.* from T1 bd
where bd.version in ( select max(bd1.version) from T1 bd1
where bd1.number = bd.number)
```

can you tell me what is wrong in the above query.

Comment: What's wrong with your code? It should work I guess.

Comment: it'll display all the records

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select bd.* from T1 bd
where bd.version in ( select max(bd1.version) from T1 bd1
where bd1.number = bd.number group by bd1.number)
```